# Field Index configuration

Tags: marklogic

while configuring field index in Marklogic using admin configuration, for **Excluded Elements**, can I use comma separated values for attribute **Value**. Currently I am doing it this way.

[image]

So just wanted to confirm whether I can use single line with 'Value' column value as 'active,archived,failed' or not?

Comment: please start accepting your valid answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The content of the 'value' is treated like a single value. The system would have no idea of the comma being special to you rather than the value of the attribute. Yes, one could argue that since XML Schema forbids commas in attributes that this could be a special notation. However, it gets stored in MarkLogic as

```
<attribute-value>active, archived, failed</attribute-value>
```

Of course, you can just test this via a simple test of a few documents.

Comment: Thank you David for informtion

Comment: HI Sukesh. No Problem.  In your recent posts, you have not accepted an answer as fitting your needs. It helps keep Stack Overflow clean by closing questions or by elaborating on the question if you have not actually found the answer you need.